# Exersice with Argument Principle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let

$$f_n(z)=1+\frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{2!z^2}+ . . . +\frac{1}{n!z^n}$$

Then compute

$$\int_{|z|=2}^{} \frac{ f '_n (z)}{f_n(z)}\,dz. $$
I was thinking the Argument Principle because of the form of the integral and that
f is meromorfic (obviously has a pole of order n). I have some troubles to compute how many roots are in $|z|<2$. $f(z)$ is equal to
$$f(z)= \frac{n!z^n+n!z^{n-1}+(3 \cdots n)!z^{n-2}+\cdots+1}{n!z^n}$$

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for $z\neq 0$ $f_n(z)=0$  iff $z^nf_n(z)=0$, which is equivalent to $$z^n + z^{n-1} + \frac{z^{n-2}}{2!} +\cdots +\frac{1}{n!}=0,$$
now use the fact that $2^n > 2^n-1 = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k$ altogether with Rouche's Theorem to find how many roots are inside $|z|=2$ (it is clear all of them are not given by $z=0$).

Answer (score 1):

Notice that if $|z|\geq 2$ we have
$$\left|\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{2!z^2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{n! z^n}\right|\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k!|z|^k}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k! 2^k}<\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{k!2^k}=\sqrt{e}-1<\frac{2}{3}$$
so $f_n(z)$ cannot be zero since $|f_n(z)|>\frac{1}{3}$. It follows that all the roots of $f_n(z)$ lie in the region $|z|<2$ and $f_n(z)$ has a unique pole of order $n$ at the origin. By the argument principle your integral equals zero.